# Code doesn't work when using Classes/methods

Tags: c#

I have a very simple C# program, with several switch cases.
Every case uses the same function with the only difference variable value - that is, everything is *hard-coded*. Not pretty but it works.

Instead of repeating the same function, i tried to define classes/methods which is called instead. But it does not work as intended.

First, in my program I declare the following variables;

```
int hp = 100;
int gold = 10;
```

Then I have a switch/cases with the following (part of) function;

```
int monster2 = 10;
gold = gold - 2;

while (monster2 > 0 && hp > 0)
{
    int dmgdone = rnd.Next(5, 15);
    Console.WriteLine("You deal " + dmgdone);
    monster2 = monster2 - dmgdone;
    int dmg = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    Console.WriteLine("You take " + dmg);
    hp = hp - dmg;

    if (monster2 <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Monster is slain");
        gold = gold + 1;
    }

    if (hp <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You where killed");
    }
}
Console.ResetColor();
break;
```

Point is that the function adjust the variables hp and gold, and when the function ends, the user gets back to the beginning of the switch function with "correct" value of hp and gold.

I did try to write class/methods with the same function for every switch cases with the correct parameter value for the methods. However, the variable value of hp and gold is constantly 100 and 10 when using this method, it doesnt get changed in the main method. How do I change the variables in the main method, from the functions/methods in a different class?

Here is how I did the new solution;

I called the method with;

```
loc.goToLocation1();
```

and here is the class for the above;

```
class location1
{
    public void useYourSword(int hp, int gold, string name, string age)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int monster = 10;
        gold = gold - 1;

        while (monster > 0 && hp > 0)
        {
            int dmgdone = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("You deal " + dmgdone);
            monster = monster - dmgdone;
            int dmg = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("You take " + dmg);
            hp = hp - dmg;

            if (monster <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Monster is slain");
                gold = gold + 1;             
            }

            if (hp <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You where killed");
            }
        }

        Console.ResetColor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us the full revelant code ? The switch that you described, can you give us its code ?

Comment: Show the full method (signature and all) and how you're actually using it. The current code doesn't tell much. You're likely just manipulating local copies of your hp and gold values, but I can't say for certain as there is obviously some missing code here.

Comment: Please also show the part of the Main method where it calls the other method, and the method header.

Comment: *"How do I change the variables in the main method, from the functions/methods in a different class?"* -- you can have a method in the other class return a value that you assign to a variable in the main method. Look at `int dmgdone = rnd.Next(1, 10);` in your code: `rnd` is an instance of another class, and you're getting a value out of one of its methods. That's *exactly* what you want to do with your own "other class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primitive variables of the type `int` or `float` are what are called value types, which means that the variable refers to the value of those items, and if you copy the variable, or pass it to a function, you copy the data it contains.

There are also reference types, like instances of classes(AKA objects) where the variable refers to an address, and that address points to the data.  In these cases, there is only one set of data per object, and when you copy the variable or pass it to a function, you only copy the address which points to the same data.

So, if you had a class for `Player`, and you passed the player to your method, and you changed it's HP, you would be able to observe that change from your caller method

Example:

```
public class Player
{
    public int HP{get; set;}

    public Player()
    {
        HP = 100;
    }
}

...

public static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    Player player = new Player();
    reduceHP(player);
    Console.WriteLine("HP: {0}, player.HP);
}

public static void reduceHP(Player player)
{
    player.HP -= 10;
}
```

of course, you can also use the [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) and [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out) keywords, but it's not a very good design to use them unless they're **really** needed

Answer (score 1):

Even though you definetely shouldn't use OOP (i.e. working with classes and objects) like that, you could use references. It would work like that:

```
internal static class P
{
    private static void Main ()
    {
        int hp = 100;
        int gold = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("Before:");
        Console.WriteLine($"\tHP: {hp}\n\tGold: {gold}\n");

        location1 loc1 = new location1();

        loc1.useYourSword(ref hp, ref gold, "", "");

        Console.WriteLine("After:");
        Console.WriteLine ($"\tHP: {hp}\n\tGold: {gold}");

        Console.ReadLine ();
    }
}

class location1
{
    public void useYourSword (ref int hp, ref int gold, string name, string age)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random ();
        int monster = 10;
        gold = gold - 1;

        while (monster > 0 && hp > 0)
        {
            int dmgdone = rnd.Next (1, 10);
            Console.WriteLine ("You deal " + dmgdone);
            monster = monster - dmgdone;
            int dmg = rnd.Next (1, 10);
            Console.WriteLine ("You take " + dmg);
            hp = hp - dmg;

            if (monster <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Monster is slain");
                gold = gold + 1;
            }

            if (hp <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("You where killed");
            }
        }

        Console.ResetColor ();
    }
}
```

Which results in:

```
Before:
        HP: 100
        Gold: 10

You deal 5
You take 8
You deal 4
You take 2
You deal 5
You take 1
Monster is slain
After:
        HP: 89
        Gold: 10
```